# Windows Symlinks in Grunt Server

Tags: windows, gruntjs, symlink

it seams I have a rather strange problem. I have a JS one Page application with a huge media pool. The media assets have a very short update cycle. Much shorter than the code base. So it has its own repository.

I have to develop the application on Windows OS and don't have the option of a VM solution. I created a symlink to the media folter but when I start up the GRUNT Server Task he can't find the media files. I think this is a Windows issue. When I open the index.html file with the file protocol I have the exact same problem. I have no idea why Windows can't just follow the symlink. I get a 404 no matter what I do. Has anyone ever had a problem like that and maybe a solution.

The projekt is also developed in a team so I don't want to put some kind of URL rewrite into the server configuration because it maybe wouldn't match the system of the other developers (but they also are on Windows).

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: How did you create the link? Did you use the `mklink /J` command?

Comment: Hey. No I created the link the "easy" way with rightklick in the Windows UI

Comment: I'd recommend trying the "hard" way with the [`mklink /J` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.11).aspx) to ensure that it's a directory junction.

Comment: wow...so simple but so perfekt :D Thank you so much that was it. It works perfekt now thank you :)

Comment: You might want to consider [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), including in the answer what it was that you did that didn't work and what did. It's possible that information might be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "mistake" was to go the simple way and create a symlink in the Windows UI by rightclicking.

By using the mklink command I was able to create a symlink that works perfectly with the Server

```
mklink /j <name> <target>
```

Thank you cartan for the help :D

Comment: Not working in Windows 10... the changes are not triggering the update on the symlink folder...